How do I hide parameter hints when the cursor moves away from a function call or manually hide the parameter hints?
Example code in Monaco Editor Playground
In Monaco Editor, once I've displayed the parameter hints, I find that I can almost never close them (only possible by manually pressing the 'esc' key or switching focus). Is there a way to automatically hide parameter hints when the cursor leaves the function call or to hide them manually?
However, in VSCode, once I perform completion, the parameter hints show up and they will hide after the cursor moves out of scope.
What I try:
myEditor.onDidChangeCursorPosition(() => {
   // can't manually trigger editor action
})

